# jquery .getJSON() doesn't catch "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: jquery, error-handling

How do we make `.getJSON function()` to detect `500 Internal Server error`.  I tried adding 
`.error()`, `.complete(status)` functions to check for return status, but none of them are working.  Looks like jQuery doesn't honor the error.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

Setup function to catch error like this

**jQuery Ajax Error Handling Function**

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

get called when you try like this

```
// jQuery AJAX Error Handler
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php"
});
```

For more detail check this post : [**jquery-ajax-error-handling-function**](http://www.unseenrevolution.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function/)

---

The `$.getJSON` function does not return the errors you would like; use `$.ajax` instead:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
      alert( "SUCCESS:  " + data );
    },
    error: function( data ) {
      alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
    }
  });
```

also try out error function like this for more detail

```
error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
```

Comment: Nope. this is not working for me. :(.  I am using Firefox (if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `$.getJSON()` not `$.ajax()`

```
$("#debug").ajaxError(function(event, xhr, opt, exception){
  // do your things.
});
```

But this handler catch all ajax errors. So you need handle what ajax is running. If you don't want to display `#debug`, set `display: none` in css.